# jQuery text() method doesn't work on textnodes

Tags: jquery, textnode

jQuery [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method doesn't work on textNodes:

```js
$('div').contents().filter(function(){
  return this.nodeType === 3;
}).text("new text");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   textNode text doesn't change
</div>
```

My question is **what could be the reason for that?**

Is this regarding withespace text nodes hard to handle? And/or deeper level descendant text nodes than only children ones?

***I'm not asking how to change it***, i know workarounds but why *jq* `text()` method doesn't support text nodes? I'd expect using this method on any text node being able to change its node value.

I'm quite sure there is a good reason for that, i cannot just getting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what could be the reason for that?

Because that's not what `text` is designed to do. From [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

> ...set the text contents of the matched **elements**

*(My emphasis)*

**Why** it's not designed to do that is a question for John Resig and/or the current set of jQuery maintainers, but at a guess, having it handle text nodes as well as elements would complicate the method. It would have to check the `nodeType` and set `nodeValue` if it were a text node, or do what it currently does (I don't know whether they do `innerText`/`textContent` or append a text node, probably the former) for an element.

Most of jQuery is element-centric, ignoring other nodes. `contents` is one of the very few methods that works at the node level.

Comment: Wouldn't just check in `text()` method for nodetype textNode and then use `nodeValue` to set text enough simple?

Comment: @A.Wolff: Yes. Which complicates the method.

Comment: Ok i think this is the main reason `jQuery is element-centric` indeed. That's just quite 'strange' than a method called `text()` doesn't work on text.

Comment: @A.Wolff: If you want to go down the "strange" path with regard to the jQuery API, you have a long walk ahead of you. ;-)

Comment: The most 'strange' part is that  `text()` getter works perfectly fine, only the setter...

Comment: @A.Wolff: That part doesn't surprise me, since the method's purpose is to gather up the text of the set. `text` is a weird one, even for the jQuery API: All the other accessor methods (`val`, `attr`, `prop`, and so on) just get from the *first* element in the set, but `text` gets from *all* elements in the set: http://jsfiddle.net/uozdnb04/ This is what I mean about it being a long path...

Comment: Ya, i think `text()` accessor should work the same as `html()` (the most relevant comparaison i can think of)

Comment: Thanks, this is the relevant answer. I always appreciate to read your posts :)